# Removing backslash (escape character) from a string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to work on my own JSON parser. I have an input string that I want to tokenize:

`input = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"num\": 3}"`

How do I remove the escape character `\` so that it is not a part of my tokens?

Currently, my solution using `delete` works:

`tokens = input.delete('\\"').split("")`

`=> ["{", " ", "f", "o", "o", ":", " ", "b", "a", "r", ",", " ", "n", "u", "m", ":", " ", "3", "}"]`

However, when I try to use `gsub`, it fails to find any `\"`.

`tokens = input.gsub('\\"', '').split("")`

`=> ["{", " ", "\"", "f", "o", "o", "\"", ":", " ", "\"", "b", "a", "r", "\"", ",", " ", "\"", "n", "u", "m", "\"", ":", " ", "3", "}"]`

I have two questions:

**1. Why does gsub not work in this case?**

**2. How do I remove the backslash (escape) character? I currently have to remove the backslash character with the quotes to make this work.**

Comment: @emaillenin I know there's `JSON.parse`, but I want to learn some data structure/algo so I figure this is a good start.

Comment: You don't need to escape the backslash in the gsub('\\"',''). Also, you may run into issues with other 'escaping-required' values in an embedded JSON string, so you may want to generalize the code to handle stuff like unicode characters in key names, or apostrophes embedded (which i think isnt legal json, but does pop up).

Comment: Why the downvote? I know what Huy is doing might seem silly to seasoned professionals, but it's exactly the kind of question a new person like myself will stumble upon when first researching JSON parsing.

Comment: @BoomShadow LOL. Thanks for reminding me of this beast. It's always great looking back

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you write:

```
input = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"num\": 3}"
```

The actual string stored in input is:

```
{ "foo": "bar", "num": 3}
```

The escape `\"` here is interpreted by Ruby parser, so that it can distinguish between the boundary of a string (the left most and the right most `"`), and a normal character `"` in a string (the escaped ones).

`String#delete` deletes *a character set* specified the first parameter, rather than a pattern. All characters that is in the first parameter will be removed. So by writing

```
input.delete('\\"')
```

You got a string with all `\` and `"` removed from `input`, rather than a string with all `\"` sequence removed from `input`. This is wrong for your case. It may cause unexpected behavior some time later.

`String#gsub`, however, substitute a pattern (either regular expression or plain string).

```
input.gsub('\\"', '')
```

means find all `\"` (two characters in a sequence) and replace them with empty string. Since there isn't `\` in `input`, nothing got replaced. What you need is actually:

```
input.gsub('"', '')
```

Answer (score 13):

You do *not* have backslashes in your string. You have quotes in your string, which need to be escaped when placed in a double-quoted string. Look:

```
input = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"num\": 3}"
puts input
# => { "foo": "bar", "num": 3}
```

You are removing - phantoms.

```
input.delete('\\"')
```

will delete any characters in its argument. Thus, you delete any non-existent backslashes, and also delete all quotes. Without quotes, the default display method (`inspect`) will not need to escape anything.

```
input.gsub('\\"', '')
```

will try to delete the sequence `\"`, which does not exist, so `gsub` ends up doing nothing.

Make sure you know what the difference between string representation (`puts input.inspect`) and string content (`puts input`) is, and note the backslashes as the artifacts of the representation.

That said, I have to echo emaillenin: writing a correct JSON parser is not simple, and you can't do it with regular expressions (or at least, not with *regular* regular expressions; it might be possible with Oniguruma). It needs a proper parser like treetop or rex/racc, since it has a lot of corner cases that are easy to miss (chief among them being, ironically, escaped characters).

Answer (score 6):

`input.gsub(/[\"]/,"")` will also work.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex pattern:

```
> input = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"num\": 3}"
> input.gsub(/"/,'').split("")

> => ["{", " ", "f", "o", "o", ":", " ", "b", "a", "r", ",", " ", "n", "u", "m", ":", " ", "3", "}"]
```

That is actually a double quote only. The slash is to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the reasons, why this string appeared?

Just in case, check your code for repeating of the `to_json` method on Hash or something else.

```rb
{ "foo": "bar", "num": 3}.to_json #=> { "foo": "bar", "num": 3}
{ "foo": "bar", "num": 3}.to_json.to_json #=> "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"num\": 3}"
```